# WebServiceCallout in InstallHandler

Tags: webservices, postinstall

I have a package with a post-install script.
The script calls a class which uses WebServiceCallout.
When running separately, it is OK, but when running in the Post Install script context, it fails.

Is there a limitation about doing WebServiceCallouts from a Post Install script?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [InstallHander](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_install_handler.htm) interface then you can only perform a callout asynchronously. Placing your callout in an `@future` method should resolve the issue.

Comment: I have found out the error occurs because I'm using UserInfo.getSessionId() with is not available in @future methods, so I pass it in, only to found out that it's not available in InstallHandler during an installation either! Salesforce - making easy thing hard, and hard things impossible.

Comment: Correct. As stated in the documentation for the InstallHandler interface: _It runs as a special system user that represents your package, so all operations performed by the script appear to be done by your package._

Comment: Is there ANY way round this? I am trying to update profiles using Financial Force's Metadata API wrapper https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/. My whole project is about to hit the rocks..